# Python Documentation Tools

Tags: python, documentation

I'm researching open-source tools and packages to generate Python documentation for modules and functions containing docstrings.

I understand [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/index.html) is good for parsing manually created docstrings written with the[reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html) markup syntax.

A second option I found relevant is [epydoc](https://epydoc.sourceforge.net/index.html), which can also parse reStructuredText. It appears to be automated rather than manual, and focused on documenting APIs.

Is there a use case for both including both tools?

Are here any other tools to consider?

Answer (score 0):

As of February 2018, [Peter Kong's medium article](https://medium.com/@peterkong/comparison-of-python-documentation-generators-660203ca3804) provides a good review of the available Python documentation tools.

It seems that epydoc may not support Python3 and a successor has been developed. Sphinx provides the more comprehensive solution while [Pdoc](https://pdoc.dev/) is simpler to install and may suffice for smaller projects.